# Heroku can't find ts-node

Tags: typescript, heroku

I am using [Colyseus](https://colyseus.io/) for my multiplayer game. The framework generated a typescript server which I tried to deploy to Heroku. I am getting the following error in my logs:

```
2019-08-18T09:45:55.362304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-08-18T09:45:55.363375+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! my-app@1.0.0 start: `ts-node index.ts`
2019-08-18T09:45:55.363477+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-08-18T09:45:55.363677+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2019-08-18T09:45:55.363800+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@1.0.0 start script.
2019-08-18T09:45:55.363912+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-08-18T09:45:55.373038+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-08-18T09:45:55.373380+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-08-18T09:45:55.373520+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-08-18T09_45_55_365Z-debug.log
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "npm init template for bootstraping an empty Colyseus project",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node index.ts",
    "loadtest": "colyseus-loadtest loadtest/example.ts --room my_room --numClients 2",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/colyseus/create-colyseus/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/colyseus/create-colyseus#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@colyseus/loadtest": "^0.10.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "ts-node": "^8.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@colyseus/monitor": "^0.10.0",
    "@colyseus/social": "^0.10.2",
    "colyseus": "^0.10.7",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-jwt": "^5.3.1"
  }
}
```

This is the `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

Why can't Heroku find `ts-node`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ts-node` is listed in your `devDependencies` but [they aren't available at runtime out of the box](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation):

> By default, Heroku will install all dependencies listed in `package.json` under `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.
>
> After running the installation and [build steps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#heroku-specific-build-steps) Heroku will strip out the packages declared under `devDependencies` before deploying the application.

If you need `ts-node` at runtime I suggest moving it to your `dependencies`.

Other solutions would be to use it only at build time (I'm not sure if this is possible with `ts-node` but it would probably involve compiling your TypeScript to JavaScript) or [configuring Heroku not to strip your `devDependencies`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning). I *strongly* advise against this last option—`devDependencies` shouldn't be required in production.