# How to solve vue-cli-service: not found proplem on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, vue-cli

I have problem trying to deply my app named tr3 (, which is working good on localhost, and I also  learned to deploy "test app" using heroku, everything was fine).
But now, when I have used command

git push heroku master

There is a message

```
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 22.2M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v8
remote:        https://stark-oasis-45806.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy... done.
To https://git.heroku.com/stark-oasis-45806.git
   12055ef..fbc5e05  master -> master
```

But link https://stark-oasis-45806.herokuapp.com/ leads to an error

```
020-06-19T17:42:19.575287+00:00 app[web.1]: > tr3@0.1.0 start /app
2020-06-19T17:42:19.575288+00:00 app[web.1]: > npm run  serve
2020-06-19T17:42:19.575288+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-19T17:42:20.037740+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-19T17:42:20.037766+00:00 app[web.1]: > tr3@0.1.0 serve /app
2020-06-19T17:42:20.037767+00:00 app[web.1]: > vue-cli-service serve
2020-06-19T17:42:20.037767+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-19T17:42:20.045068+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
2020-06-19T17:42:20.049281+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-19T17:42:20.049568+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-06-19T17:42:20.049812+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
```

Also here is my package.json

```
{
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.x"
  },
  "name": "tr3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "start": "npm run  serve",
    "heroku-postinstall": "npm install && npm run build"
  },
  "heroku-postinstall": "npm install && npm run build",
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.3.4",
     "vuex": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku can't find ts-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543386/heroku-cant-find-ts-node)

Comment: It helped, thank you

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem a few days ago, I am new with Vue.js and Heroku, but I was able to find this information which helped me with the problem and I hope it helps other people.

Create the static.json file at the same level of package.json:

```
{
    "root": "dist",
    "clean_urls": true,
    "routes": {
        "/**": "index.html"
    }
}
```

Add static.json file to git

```
git add static.json
git commit -m "add static configuration"
```

Deploy to Heroku

```
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-static
git push heroku master
```

Source of information: [Deployment | Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#heroku)

Comment: this doesn't work anymore if anybody sees this after me

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by running:

`heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false`

I was helped by this [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/hmmjuu/vuecliservice_not_found_when_trying_to_deploy_to/) and [Heroku's Skip pruning](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning) instructions. Turns out my little vue app with no functionality needed to access `devDependencies`. I'm not sure if this is the most appropriate thing to do, but it solved my problem.

Comment: vue-cli-service was in my dev-dependencies so this worked

Answer (score 3):

For those who the above solutions didnt work you guys can try add "@vue/cli-service" dependencie on your package.json in dependencies.

explanation: this is because @vue/cli-service is only on devDependencies so when you deploy ur app on production that dependencie is not being downloaded in your project.

Comment: I tried this before the other answers above it and it didn't work. Still getting the same error :/.