# Heroku deployment failing: Failed to load plugin 'cypress' declared in 'package.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-cypress'

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm, eslint, cypress

**Update #2 after some more research**

Looking into the build logs some more, it looks like Cypress gets installed via a postinstall hook that downloads a binary that Heroku doesn't pick up in the build process for some reason unless config is set to `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`. Comparing the [failed build log](https://gist.github.com/ddehart/9e0ca72a3f20f104e05d70eed6de6c64#file-failing-build-log-L50) with the [successful build log](https://gist.github.com/ddehart/9e0ca72a3f20f104e05d70eed6de6c64#file-failing-build-log-L50), this postinstall hook doesn't run:

```
> cypress@6.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_0453cc7d/frontend/node_modules/cypress
```

Why this and potentially other `devDependencies` don't get installed prior to `npm run build` doesn't appear to be documented and runs contrary to Heroku's documentation that `devDependencies` are installed by default.

**Update #1 with more build info**

Here's a gist that shows the failing build log and the succeeding build log (after configuring Heroku not to prune `devDependencies` using `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`).

https://gist.github.com/ddehart/9e0ca72a3f20f104e05d70eed6de6c64

The pruning appears to be initiated after the build process installed Cypress, so it's not clear why setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` prompted the Cypress installation, despite Heroku's documentation that says:

> By default, Heroku will install all dependencies listed in `package.json` under `dependencies` and `devDependencies`.

**Original question**

I'm getting this `npm run build` error when deploying to Heroku:

`Failed to load plugin 'cypress' declared in 'package.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-cypress'`

Here's my `package.json` for reference:

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open",
    "cypress:run": "cypress run"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "plugin:cypress/recommended"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/cypress": "^7.0.2",
    "cypress": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2"
  }
}
```

The project was initiated using Create React App. `npm run build` succeeds without any issues locally, so I first thought maybe Heroku was pruning `devDependencies`, but looking back at other build logs that succeeded show that pruning happens after a successful build.

If it helps, here's my `package.json` from the last successful build.

```json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "cypress:open": "cypress open"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "plugin:cypress/recommended"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^5.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.11.2"
  }
}
```

I **think** the build is complaining about this, although that hasn't changed at all from the last successful build.

```json
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "plugin:cypress/recommended"
    ]
  },
```

Removing that plugin declaration of course ruins Cypress in my IDE. Is there any way to work around the build error or troubleshoot on the Heroku instance itself?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku can't find ts-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543386/heroku-cant-find-ts-node)

Comment: @Chris it's related, but there must be something about the internals of the Heroku build process I don't understand. `devDependency` pruning happens after the build process (which fails). For whatever it's worth, setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` prompted npm to install Cypress, which cleared the error. I'd love to understand why, though, as keeping this configuration seems suboptimal.

Comment: "`devDependency` pruning happens after the build process (which fails)"—your question doesn't show this.  Please [edit] it and add more context for your build error, so we can see the full stack trace.

Comment: @Chris I just added additional info. Thanks for your help

Comment: It looks like the issue was more with my `eslintConfig` than it was with `devDependencies`. I still don't completely understand what changed since previous builds succeeded, but at least I avoided the config @Chris recommended against in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`, I ended up moving the Cypress `eslintConfig` into its own `.eslintrc.json` file within the `cypress` directory. Since Heroku only seems to be getting hung up on the Cypress plugin referenced in the main `package.json`, removing that configuration altogether fixed the Heroku build issue without affecting my IDE and without having to rely on the non-standard `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` setting.

Per [Cypress's documentation](https://github.com/cypress-io/eslint-plugin-cypress), the `.eslintrc.json` file just needs this for the recommended rules:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "plugin:cypress/recommended"
  ]
}
```