# Is it possible to disable ESLint when running npm run build for a React app?

Tags: heroku, npm, create-react-app, eslint, react-scripts

I have an app initiated using Create React App, so `npm run build` runs `react-scripts build`. I recently installed `prettier` and so added a `.eslintrc.json` file to the project root to load the `prettier` plugin. `npm run build` works as expected locally, but, when deploying the app to Heroku, `npm run build` tries to run ESLint and fails because the plugins are `devDependencies` rather than `dependencies`.

```
Failed to load plugin 'prettier' declared in '.eslintrc.json': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'
```

[From prior wrangling with a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054965/heroku-deployment-failing-failed-to-load-plugin-cypress-declared-in-package/65056443#65056443), I know that I can set `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` in Heroku so that it will install `devDependencies`, which actually does resolve the deployment issue. Nevertheless, I'm curious to learn if there's another solution that doesn't require setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`.

Is it possible to prevent `npm run build` in this scenario from running ESLint altogether or to prevent it from trying to access the plugins specified in `.eslintrc.json`? I acknowledge that adding `.eslintrc.json` to `.gitignore` is one solution, but I want the ESLint configuration in my repo.

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Could you please help? I have the same :-(

Comment: @OleksiiSytar looking back on my commit history for the project I was working on when I ran into this, I don't think I did solve it. I just had to keep `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` in my Heroku config :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running this:

`"build": "DISABLE_ESLINT_PLUGIN=true react-scripts build",`

This will disable the `eslint` during the build phase.

Answer (score 0):

you can run "npm run eject" to generate webpack configuration files, and then modify "webpack.config.js"，delete the eslint configuration