# Deploy node.js / express / mongoDB ( with typescript ) in heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, heroku

Before, in the backend i would not use typescript, i would just use pure javascript, but know, this is my first backend app with typescript.

I want to deploy of course this app to heroku, but, i wonder if in the procfile component i have to tell heroku to get the server running in the server.ts, or in the server.js in the dist folder.

What i'm trying to say, is that, should i compile my code to translate it into pure javascript in the dist folder in order to deplot, or is it okay just to just run the server in the server.ts file ?

This is how my project looks like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is ultimately just there to help you structure your code properly, as it is meant to be compiled to JavaScript. While you can run your server via `ts-node` on a VM, it is simpler to just compile it to JS and run it on your VM, as at that point it is no different from a typical NodeJS application. Other advantages are smaller build files since your js files will take up less space and startup time.

That being said there is no stopping you from using ts-node on heroku by putting `ts-node index.ts` inside your `package.json` `start` script, (also ts-node should be in `dependencies` not `devDependencies`), but personally I'd go down the compilation route as that is pretty much just another NodeJS application.

See [Heroku can't find ts-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543386/heroku-cant-find-ts-node)

Comment: Than you so much for the answer ! I'll compile the code to JS and give it a try, thanks again !